# HTML entity for check mark

Tags: html

Is there an HTML entity for a check mark?

[image: green checkmark]

I've searched for it in various html entities cheat sheets but didn't find it

Comment: CSS escaped code: `\2713`

Answer (score 215, accepted):

Something like this?

### ✔

if so, type the HTML `&#10004;`

And `&#10003;` gives a lighter one:

✓

Comment: Where did you find this? I'm looking for a different entity, but in the same family.

Comment: Googling would have given you all you need (HTML Entities) - I.E http://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html and http://www.danshort.com/HTMLentities/?w=dingb , for example :)

Answer (score 22):

Here are a couple: http://www.amp-what.com/unicode/search/check%20mark

&#x2713
&#x2714

Comment: I appreciated this answer because it explains the difference between &#10004; and &#10003; Thanks!

Comment: Can we get a checkmark in HTML that doesn't look like Comic Sans? Is that too much to ask?

Answer (score 9):

HTML and XML entities are just a way of referencing a Unicode code-point in a way that reliably works regardless of the encoding of the actual page, making them useful for using esoteric Unicode characters in a page using 7-bit ASCII or some other encoding scheme, ideally on a one-off basis. They're also used to escape the `<`, `>`, `"` and `&` characters as these are reserved in SGML.

Anyway, Unicode has a number of tick/check characters, as per Wikipedia ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tick_(check_mark) ).

Ideally you should save/store your HTML in a Unicode format like UTF-8 or 16, thus obviating the need to use HTML entities to represent a Unicode character. Nonetheless use: `&#x2714;` ✔.

```
&#x2714;
```

> ✔

Is using hex notation and is the same as

```
$#10004;
```

(as `2714` in base 16 is the same as `10004` in base 10)

Answer (score 0):

There is HTML entity &#10003 but it doesn't work in some older browsers.