# How to draw checkbox or tick mark in GitHub Markdown table?

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I am able to draw checkbox in Github README.md lists using

```
- [ ] (for unchecked checkbox)
- [x] (for checked checkbox)
```

But this is not working in table. Does anybody know how to implement checkbox or checkmark in GitHub Markdown table?

Comment: Check out GitHub Blog https://github.blog/2014-04-28-task-lists-in-all-markdown-documents/

Comment: Markdown requires you to add some text after the checkbox. E.g., `- [ ] myLabel`

Comment: Seems that checkboxes are not available with [Stackoverflow's Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)!

Answer (score 1136, accepted):

Try adding a `-`  before the `[ ]` or `[x]`. That's an `-` followed by a blank space  . An unchecked box also need a space   between the brackets.

Below is an example from Github blog.

```
### Solar System Exploration, 1950s – 1960s

- [ ] Mercury
- [x] Venus
- [x] Earth (Orbit/Moon)
- [x] Mars
- [ ] Jupiter
- [ ] Saturn
- [ ] Uranus
- [ ] Neptune
- [ ] Comet Haley
```

It appears like below:

[image: Resultant Image]

Here's how one could do the same in a table:

```
| Task           | Time required | Assigned to   | Current Status | Finished | 
|----------------|---------------|---------------|----------------|-----------|
| Calendar Cache | > 5 hours  |  | in progress | - [x] ok?
| Object Cache   | > 5 hours  |  | in progress | [x] item1<br/>[ ] item2
| Object Cache   | > 5 hours  |  | in progress | <ul><li>- [x] item1</li><li>- [ ] item2</li></ul>
| Object Cache   | > 5 hours  |  | in progress | <ul><li>[x] item1</li><li>[ ] item2</li></ul>


- [x] works
- [x] works too
```

Here's how it looks:

[image]

Comment: There was a formatting mistake in question initially. It is working for lists but not for table.

Comment: This looks good, but the checkboxes are broken. If you click a checkbox, it does nothing. Ordinarily clicking a GitHub Markdown checkbox checks/unchecks it. Workaround is to manually edit the HTML, which isn't great, but doable.

Comment: This creates just the appearance of a checkbox. The item doesn't actually respond to click events, which cancels the purpose of them: check from md rendered mode, rather than raw text.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus do you mean this does not work in issues/merge requests? As in general, while checkboxes are clickable in GitHub / GitLab issues and merge requests as, for such locations, it makes sense as sort of a shoping list, what woud be the meaning of user clicking on a checkbox in documentation? Would you really like to see your markdown edited?

Comment: To me it honestly seems broken on GitHub's side.

Comment: This markdown checkbox also works for the Github "projects" tab, inside your Cards on your Kanban board.

Comment: Make sure the don't have spaces between parentheses and `x`. `[ x ]` won't work but `[x]` will.

Comment: (FYI) Sadly, this solution does not currently not work in Azure Devops

Comment: While the "ul around a checkbox in a table" approach will display correctly, it will not function correctly — the box can't be checked without dropping into edit mode and editing the markup.

Comment: @Joël well, yes, I'd like the checkbox to be clickable. There's plenty of merge requests where shopping lists are inside tables. At either rate, the determining factor, if needed, should be the scope of the document, not the type of element the checkbox appears in.

Answer (score 185):

Now emojis are supported! `:white_check_mark:` / `:heavy_check_mark:` gives a good impression and is widely supported:

```
Function | MySQL / MariaDB | PostgreSQL | SQLite
:------------ | :-------------| :-------------| :-------------
substr | :heavy_check_mark: |  :white_check_mark: | :heavy_check_mark:
```

renders to (here on older chromium 65.0.3x) :

[image]

Comment: This looks very nice in the rendered output but the downside is that it takes a lot of space in the "source code" and is not very readable there. And the readability is one of the major concepts of markdown.

Comment: I think this may be out of date as `:white_check_mark:` now looks like a green check box with a white check mark.

Comment: @davidkonrad, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59674743/90287, specifically https://gist.github.com/rxaviers/7360908. I'm using Firefox 76.0.1 and Chrome 81.0.4044.138 on Windows.

Comment: hi, do u actually have this table that shows what functions are supported in what database?

Comment: @ERJAN, [OT] Yes, and many of them, +100. It is from the docs from an internal project, which provide homogene access to various dbms'es. Where native support differs, or a SQL function is missing, functionality are tweaked so using popular SQL-functions return the exact same regardless of platform, that is what the gray tickmark indicate. Cannot promise anything, but the domain for open sourcing it **is** bought, crudder.net. All I need is time.

Comment: @davidkonrad thx u David! i wish it was online, but not yet.. i will wait

Comment: @davidkonrad, pls do upload it on github if possible

Comment: If anyone is looking for a red cross its code is `:x:`

Comment: Now in VS code https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bierner.markdown-emoji required for emoji

Answer (score 116):

I used `&#9744;` (☐) for `[ ]` and `&#9745;` (☑) for `[x]` and it works for [marked.js](https://github.com/markedjs/marked) which says it is compatible with Github markdown. I based my solution on [answers for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183982/html-entity-for-check-mark). See also [this informative answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18294705/1571426).

Update: I should have mentioned that when you do it this way, you do not need the `<ul>`, e.g:

```
| Unchecked | Checked |
| --------- | ------- |
| &#9744;   | &#9745; |
```

Comment: This works too aside from accepted answer. In fact, I have already used it successfully on GitHub. Thanks for pointing it out for everyone. I should have done that earlier.

Comment: &#10004; for '✔'

Comment: Note that some emoji characters render differently in GitHub issue display vs. in the editor: ☑ becomes a box check with a **red** mark despite looking black&white in the editor. The check mark button ✅ becomes a "white" check mark when rendered, despite looking green in the editor. The check mark ✔️ looks black in the editor, but gets rendered as a **green** check mark in the issue.

Answer (score 113):

```
|checked|unchecked|crossed|
|---|---|---|
|&check;|_|&cross;|
|&#x2611;|&#x2610;|&#x2612;|
```

| checked | unchecked | crossed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ✓ | _ | ✗ |
| ☑ | ☐ | ☒ |

Where

- ✓ via [HTML Entity Code](https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/symbols/check-mark)
- ✗ via [HTML Entity Code](https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/symbols/ballot-x/)
- _ via underscore character
- ☑, ☐ and ☒ via [HTML ballot box codes](https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/symbols/)
- table via markdown [table syntax](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#tables).

Answer (score 78):

There are very nice `Emoji` icons instructions available at

- https://gist.github.com/rxaviers/7360908
- or at https://github.com/StylishThemes/GitHub-Dark/wiki/Emoji

You can check them out. I hope you would find suitable icons for your writing.

[image: Nice Emojis]

Best,

Answer (score 71):

You can use emojis

```
Done? | Name
:---:| ---
⬜️| Nope
✅| Yep
```

Comment: what should i write for using first emoji? I know, that second is ":heavy_check_mark:"

Comment: for uncheck box use `:white_large_square` and for check box use `:white_check_mark`

Comment: List of Github [supported emojis](https://github.com/ikatyang/emoji-cheat-sheet/blob/master/README.md)

Answer (score 33):

Unfortunately, the accepted answer doesn't work for me (I'm using GitHub flavoured markdown).

It occurs to me since we're adding HTML elements, why not just add an `<input>` instead.

```
| demo                                              | demo |
| ------------------------------------------------- | ---- |
| <input type="checkbox" disabled checked /> works  |      |
| <input type="checkbox" disabled /> works here too |      |
```

This should work in any environment cuz it's plain HTML (see FYI below).

[image: Rendered result]

> *FYI, this example was tested in VS Code markdown preview mode(GitHub flavoured), the screenshot is also taken in VS Code preview mode. It's **not** working on GitHub.*

> *Emoji mentioned above is a good alternative, if this doesn't work in your target environment.*

Comment: This won't display in Github

Answer (score 16):

#### 09 2021

If you have an issue with the standard markdown code. You can use emojis.

#### Native Github

If you are using GitHub's default emojis, you can use these. Something to note is that there is no uncheck, so you have to use different emojis to get that look.

⬜
`:white_large_square`

✅
`:white_check_mark`

#### Source

`:white_large_square`: https://github.com/ikatyang/emoji-cheat-sheet/blob/master/README.md#geometric
`:white_check_mark`: https://github.com/ikatyang/emoji-cheat-sheet/blob/master/README.md#other-symbol

Complete list
https://github.com/ikatyang/emoji-cheat-sheet/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 15):

Edit the document or wiki page, and use the `- [ ]` and `- [x]` syntax to update your task list. Furthermore you can refer to [this link](https://github.com/blog/1825-task-lists-in-all-markdown-documents).

Comment: You can create tables with pipes | and hyphens - to create a table and inside of that table you can use the - [ ] and - [x] syntax. this is how i draw a checkbox.

Comment: @JosephCharles Please can you provide sample code to show how you got it working in a table?

Comment: This will not work and does not answer the question.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I have that helps you and others about markdown checkbox table. Enjoy!

```
| Projects | Operating Systems | Programming Languages   | CAM/CAD Programs | Microcontrollers and Processors | 
|---------------------------------- |---------------|---------------|----------------|-----------|
| <ul><li>[ ] Blog </li></ul>       | <ul><li>[ ] CentOS</li></ul>        | <ul><li>[ ] Python </li></ul> | <ul><li>[ ] AutoCAD Electrical </li></ul> | <ul><li>[ ] Arduino </li></ul> |
| <ul><li>[ ] PyGame</li></ul>   | <ul><li>[ ] Fedora </li></ul>       | <ul><li>[ ] C</li></ul> | <ul><li>[ ] 3DsMax </li></ul> |<ul><li>[ ] Raspberry Pi </li></ul> |
| <ul><li>[ ] Server Info Display</li></ul>| <ul><li>[ ] Ubuntu</li></ul> | <ul><li>[ ] C++ </li></ul> | <ul><li>[ ] Adobe AfterEffects </li></ul> |<ul><li>[ ]  </li></ul> |
| <ul><li>[ ] Twitter Subs Bot </li></ul> | <ul><li>[ ] ROS </li></ul>    | <ul><li>[ ] C# </li></ul> | <ul><li>[ ] Adobe Illustrator </li></ul> |<ul><li>[ ]  </li></ul> |
```

Answer (score 2):

Following is how I draw a checkbox in a table!

```
| Checkbox Experiments | [ ] unchecked header  | [x] checked header  |
| ---------------------|:---------------------:|:-------------------:|
| checkbox             | [ ] row               | [x] row             |
```

Displays like this: 
[image]

Comment: It's not working for me. Is it for Github flavored markdown?

Comment: I see, somehow it doesn't render with `Github flavoured markdown`. But works fine for other markdown previewers.

Answer (score 0):

The following works well on GitHub

```
| Selection |        |
| --------- | ------ |
| <li>- [ ] </li> |  |

| Selection |        |
| --------- | ------ |
| <li>- [x] </li> |  |
```

[image]

Comment: For some reason it also draws a bullet point underneath the checboxes for me: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/FwghXuYWwAIlhfC?format=png&name=240x240

Comment: I also got a bullet point rendering. Using a `ul` worked for me:
`<ul><li> - [ ] </li></ul>`

Answer (score 0):

by adding cross x in col without spaces you can check desired checkbox

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

### Dec 2023:

This is the only thing that worked for me.

Please make sure that you remove the whitespaces around the `x`, since GitHub adds them by default:

`- [x]`